# Align left edge to center - RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following requirement (drastically simplified):

[image]

**text 2** must start from the CENTER of the screen.

I could only achieve this using **LinearLayout's**:

```
<more_code></more_code><LinearLayout
                                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                                    android:weightSum="2"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                    <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="test one"/>
                                    <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="test two"/>
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                    <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="test three"/>

                                    <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="test four"/>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout><more_code></more_code>
```

Since I have already too many nested views (thus getting a *myfile.xml has more the 10 levels, bad for performance* warning) I'd like to know if I can get the same result with one **RelativeLayout**. I've been through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) but I could not find a property that allows me that.

Comment: use two linearlayouts for that row and use layout weights as 50% of sum weight

Comment: If I add third layout it did not goes under the first one

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is very easy if you will accept 1 empty view of 0dp by 0dp as overhead. In my opinion this is better than having too many nested views, but this can serve as a reference for the other views.

Use an empty `Space`(of 0x0 px). If you center this `Space` horizontally, you can use it as a reference like so:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Empty layout (0x0 dp) centered horizontally -->
    <Space android:id="@+id/dummy" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <!-- Align to parent left -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="test one"/>

    <!-- to right of the previous one, and to left of the dummy -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_one"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dummy"
        android:text="test two"/>

    <!-- Align to right of the dummy -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dummy"
        android:text="test three"/>

    <!-- Align to right of the previous one, and parent right -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_four"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_three"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="test four"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Interesting! if there's nothing better I'll accept this one, although `dummy` still gives me that warning.

Comment: Ok, so you are already 10 levels deep. In that case, I would certainly prefer this option (which adds 1 'useless' linearlayout), over the weights=1 options (which adds 2 'useless' linearlayouts && adds an extra nested level)! Good luck

Comment: Indeed! btw it's hard not to get to level 10 when using `TabHost`

Comment: I would recommend use `Space` instead of an empty `LinearLayout`. Tested with `Space` with `width` and `height` at `0dp`, worked as expected. :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Space view, that's awesome! Saved me the trouble of nesting two layouts and using center

Comment: One warning: `Space` requires API level 14. The original solution of a 1x1 `LinearLayout` works if compatibility with earlier APIs is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can align it to Parent's Left Using alignParentLeft="true"

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code(untested):

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <!--  ListRow Left side text-->

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/lefttextview" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <!-- center -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lefttextview"
            android:text="text2"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't understand the exact problem. What you want is text2 from center so firstly use relative layout as its easier to do placements in relative layout rather than a linear layout which places controls one after another with only orientation defined.
And in that you can use a property center_in_parent to true and then align the text1 to its left. I hope this answers your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a dummy `View` that has `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` with an id. Then add your `TextView` with the attribute `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id_of_dummy_view"` to position it. There might be an easier way to do this but I'm not able to test at the moment.