# How can I position the end edge of a TextView to the center of the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple `TextView` inside of a `RelativeLayout`.

I want to position **end edge** of `TextView` **to center** of the `RelativeLayout` as in image below

[image: Desired result]

I found something like `android:layout_toStartOf=...`

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">  
    <TextView 
          android:text="TextView" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toStartOf=...
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But this only aligns the end edge to start of something. (Can't be used for align end edge to CENTER of layout).

Comment: And what's the question or what doesn't work, how does your code looks, etc.? Anyway welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: Moved image up to support initial problem statement, change title to include keywords and create problem statement. All so it is easier to understand what you need and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: There is already a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445560/align-left-edge-to-center-relativelayout).

You need to have a widget in the `RelativeLayout` that you can use as a reference to position the `TextView`.  An empty `Space` widget (0dp x 0dp) centered horizontally works well for this.

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Empty space widget (0x0 dp) centered horizontally -->
    <Space
        android:id="@+id/spacer" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <!-- TextView to left of the spacer-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spacer"
        android:text="awesome text!"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good answer, but i'm interested in -one line- simple code too if it exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dummy `View` centered within your `RelativeLayout` and then align the `TextView` left to it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/center_anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_anchor"
        android:text="hello world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You may also have a look at the [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) which supports percentage based dimensions and margins. That means you can specify a right margin of 50% for example.

Comment: +1 Thanks to your answer refer to `PercentRelativeLayout` and also to your suggestions about good questioning. Both answers are the same at the time, but I like to tick @5happy1 to help him grow with respect both of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using PercentRelativeLayout

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_marginRightPercent="50%" />
```